# What does `mdadm --manage /dev/md1` do? Do I need to "undo" it?

Tags: mdadm

I ran this hoping to find out a bit about my array (I now know I should have used `--detail`).  But I'm not clear what the `--manage` option does.  It gave no output, and just put me back to the bash prompt.

Do I need to run some command to undo whatever that did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mdadm --manage /dev/md1` does nothing.

The `--manage` option selects Manage mode (which is the default mode anyway), and the argument `/dev/md1` selects the RAID device to manage. The action to perform would come next, but you gave none, so none is performed.